# Mongodb store the documents id in memory before itereting?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am currelying devoloping a program that read documents from mongo and write them in a file...
something like this:

```
for doc in db.col.find(field=="bla"):
file.write(doc)
```

my question is... this process can stop for whatever reason while executing, leading to a file with for example 99% of the documents extracted and writed to the file so... ¿Is there a way to know which documents, which _id, i have no extracted? otherwise i would need to run the program again and extract all the information when i just need 1% of them. If i am right, mongo first do a index scan (or collection scan) and then fetch the document while itereing in the application, so in theory i could access those _id even before write the documents to the file but how? i dont find any information.

Comment: _"...this process can stop for whatever reason while executing"_: Is there an error message?

Comment: yes, for example if there is network problem i have that exception controled.

Comment: If it helps, you can _project_ just the `_id` field and get the `_id` values as an array. You can then iterate over the array. What information are you writing to the file (just a few fields or entire document)?

Comment: I am writing the entire document, i use json_dumps so i have everything as string.

Comment: How many documents in the collection? Each document is very large?

Comment: We are speaking of terabytes. i dont want to extract one terrabyte of data again just because some network error.

Comment: Okay, an option. It may be efficient to use the `mongoexport` command-line tool to write data as JSON to a file. Another option is, set [cursor batch size](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.batch_size).

Comment: I have been seeing the cursor batch size pretty interesting. What about showRecordID https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.showRecordId/. it seems that even after a failure i may have the recordID to know if a document has been extracted.